# Detect Extension/ Mimetype of Microsoft Office documents in Javascript using Base64 string

Tags: javascript, ms-office, mime-types, file-extension

Is there any way to determine the Mimetype/ extension of docx, pptx and xlsx formats using their base64 string.

Using File signature/ magic numbers is of no use as all of these three files start with the same string.

Is there any way to know the extension of these files using Base64 string/ Blob.

Update:
I was able to figure out the solution for this. I've posted the answer below. The solution doesn't work for older versions of the Microsoft documents .doc, .xls and .ppt. Please post your answers for them

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. All of the Microsoft office documents are built using Office Open XML standard.

The Office open XML standard uses a Zip structure to store the contents. Change the office document as a Zip file and extract the Zip file, the following contents can be seen. One file which is common to all the office documents is the [Content_Types.xml] file.
[Office document structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EH8HQ.png)

In Javascript, treat the Blob of the Office document as a Zip file and use any of the Zip libraries to extract the content. Once extracted, get the file named [Content_Types.xml] file to determine the type of the document

JSZip: https://stuk.github.io/jszip/